# How to enable to work only one card on my laptop?

Tags: nvidia, 12.10, intel, hybrid-graphics

I have a laptop with Intel HD and Nvidia GPU video cards and I have a problem with installing drivers for the second. They mess everything up. Unity don't want to start, because `GLX MISSING ON DISPLAY 0:0` and resolution of screen is 640x480, though, I can't change it in terminal.

```
xrandr -s 1920x1080
```

says this kind of mode doesn't exist.

I looked up this problem and it's due to Nvidia drivers (I tried to install 310.14, but it doesn't work with other versions neither), so I want Ubuntu to see only my Nvidia card and forget about Intel one.

How do I do it?

Comment: I have a similar problem which sounds exactly like yours. However, I use Lubuntu 12.10 and also tried installing the drivers through Nvidias script (sudo sh NVIDIA-Linux-x86-304.64.run). When I run nvidia-settings it complains that I'm not using the NVIDIA X driver and asks me to run nvidia-xconfig as root to create /etc/X11/xorg.conf, which it does, but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

An [article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics) in Ubuntu Community Help covers the subject of Hybrid Graphics.

I will outline the main things:

First you've to determine if your kernel has been compiled with the proper option. When it has this option you can use this option to activate a GPU. You can do this by terminal and with a GUI. The script for this GUI has been provided in the article.

> Note that this method is not supported by all machines and only works
>   if you are using the opensource driver (nouveau, radeon) and not the
>   proprietary ones (nvidia, fglrx).

Comment: Okay, but I am using a proprietary drivers, as I said above, it's 310.14 from nvidia's site. How do I turn off or delete drivers for intel hd graphics and turn descrete gpu?