# Is it possible to turn off integrated GPU in laptops with an Optimus card?

Tags: nvidia-optimus, hybrid-graphics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable to work only one card on my laptop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214518/how-to-enable-to-work-only-one-card-on-my-laptop)

Good morning.
I have Alienware m14x with NVidia Optimus GT555M. I would like to be able to have my laptop screen and external HDMI screen both working. Is there any way I can do it? I would prefer to turn off the integrated GPU completely and just let the PC to run on the NVIDIA if possible, but I can't find a solution for that.

Thank you for any tips